# how to delete or replace text with line pattern end with "></a>

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to delete a few lines of some text files that end with pattern like this `"></a>`. I know it can be done with sed regex, but don't know how.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this HTML? (there may be better tools for HTML).

Comment: I use bluefish to edit html and look for lines with regex like this <a id="(.+)"> </a> to get lines with patern like that for example <a id="new book"> </a>

Comment: You want to delete "a few" lines matching that pattern. Does that mean you don't want to delete _all_ those lines? Are these XML files? Is the issue finding the files or deleting the lines?

Comment: There are **plenty** of examples around; even handling of `/` in the pattern is covered there.

Answer (score 0):

1. If text files are in **/data** directory.
2. command example

```
find /data -type f -iname \*.txt -exec sed  '/"><\/a>/d' {} \;
```

3. Reference
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/how-to-delete-from-a-text-file-all-lines-that-contain-a-specific-string